# Can I operate a 500kW/1500rpms motor at 35Hz with 400kW inverter?

Tags: motor, vfd

In stock we have a 3 phase induction motor with a rated power 500kW and 1490rpms[image].

What is the smallest frequency inverter which we can use to operate this motor in a machine with a maximum power/speed 315kW/1000rpms

I think 315kW inverter (or for service factor 355kW) is enough.

But the specialists who are selling the inverter explained me that we need 500kW inverter for it, but I did not understand why?

Comment: You can, just watch the current... Or if the inverter supports a current limit, set to 300kW equivalent.

Comment: Actually I just talked with them again and I am wrong... :) If I reduce the speed to 1000rpms, the mechanical power at the motor shaft will be 1.5 times smaller, but the current is the same as per 500kW/1500rpms...since the Voltage is reduced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the load is a fan or centrifugal pump, the same torque will be required to drive the load at the lower speed. Your power calculation implies that the torque will be the same. The power will be reduce to about 70% of rated because power is torque multiple by speed. However current is proportional to torque, so the current will not be reduced. VFDs are inherently limited to their rated current, they can not provide more current when the voltage is lowered even though that means that less power is being converted.